# MaterialModal in gwt-material-1.5.0.jar fails

Tags: java, gwt, modal-dialog, material-design

I upgraded my GWT application from gwt-material-1.4.0 to gwt-material-1.5.0 and all the modal dialogs started failing. Modals just show up as a blank grayed out page without the content. Have anyone ran in to this issue and solved it?  I would like to have this resolved. I will greatly appreciate your help.  Here's my sample UiBinder.

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
 xmlns:m="urn:import:gwt.material.design.client.ui">
 <g:HTMLPanel>
   <m:MaterialModal type="DEFAULT" inDuration="500" outDuration="500"
     ui:field="aboutUsModal" backgroundColor="blue" dismissable="true">
     <m:MaterialModalContent>
       <m:MaterialTitle title="Default Modal" description="Howdy world!" />
     </m:MaterialModalContent>
     <m:MaterialModalFooter>
       <m:MaterialButton text="Close Modal" type="FLAT" />
     </m:MaterialModalFooter>
   </m:MaterialModal>
 </g:HTMLPanel>
```

Comment: Update - The GWT Material Design team published an update (gwt-material-1.5.1) with some bug fixes. Moving from gwt-material-1.5.0 to gwt-material-1.5.1 fixed this issue.

Comment: How do I mark this as resolved?